# Is Hamiltonian path NL?

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, np-complete, hamiltonian-path

[NL is what can be solved by a non-deterministic Turing machine in logspace.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NL_(complexity))

Could you non-deterministically "guess" the correct [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path) in logspace, keeping track of the current vertex (log(n) bits) and a count of how many vertices you've visited (log(n) bits)?

Does that mean finding a Hamiltonian path is NL?

(This is too simple; what is my mistake?)

A Hamiltonian path is a path that visits all vertices in a graph. The concept exists for directed and undirected graphs.

Answer (score 1):

This describes a non-deterministic [*walk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_path), not a *path*.

You may end up counting the same vertex more than once.

Given a start configuration of `(v, 0)` (meaning you're at vertex `v` and you've traversed 0 edges), when you're at configuration `(w, n-1)` (meaning now you're at vertex `w` and you've traversed `n-1` edges), all you know is that you have a `v->w` walk of length `n-1`.

If there's a Hamiltonian path, you will find it non-deterministically, however, you will not "know" that you've found it by examining the `(w, n-1)` state.

This algorithm decides walks of length `n-1`.